# Email рассылка нескольким получателям командой mailx в Linux

Tags: linux, unix

В Линукс через командную строку запускается рассылка email нескольким получателям:

```
$ echo "This is message body" | mail -s "This is Subject" someone1@example.com,someone2@example.com
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы каждый реципиент при получении письма в поле "Кому:" видел только себя, а не всех тех кому также рассылаются письма?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Особенности SMTP протокола таковы, что для выполнения условия:

> чтобы каждый реципиент при получении письма в поле "Кому:" видел
>   только себя, а не всех

необходимо отправить письмо каждому получателю отдельно.

Не важно, делаете вы это через программу `mail` в консоли, или используете язык программирования.

Поэтому, если нужно использовать консольный вариант с рассылкой по списку, то пишите скрипт с циклом по всем получателям.

Если же очень надо это делать одной командой, то воспользуйтесь маленьким "лайфхаком". Обычно называется `forward`.

Реализовать это можно по разному. Например, создать в файле /etc/aliases такую строку:

```
managers:  user1, user2, user3
```

или

```
managers:  user1@your-domain.com, user2@your-domain.com, user3@your-domain.com
```

и слать письмо на адрес `managers@your-domain.com`.

Но тут есть особенность: все получатели такого письма увидят в поле `Кому` адрес `managers@your-domain.com`.

Comment: А скажите, такой вариант будет работать: ``mailx -r --append='FROM:Vasya Ivanov <vasya@ivanov.com>' -c  --append='BCCrecipient1@domain.com' -s "test subject" recipient@domain.com -с someone1@example.com someone2@example.com`` ? Просто нет пока возможности проверить...

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto работать может быть что-то и будет (не силен я в опциях `mailx`), но поставленный вопрос достигнут не будет. Вы пытаетесь обмануть MTA в рамках одной SMTP-сессии, загрузив в нее кучу данных (которые превратятся в SMTP-заголовки), и не станут нужными/требуемыми для каждого отдельного получателя в поле "Кому".

Answer (score 2):

Типы получателей письма Cc: (копия, carbon copy) — вторичные получатели письма, которым направляется копия. Они видят и знают о наличии друг друга.

Типы получателей письма Bcc: (скрытая копия, blind carbon copy) — скрытые получатели письма, чьи адреса не показываются другим получателям.

Из этого следует, что `-b` - это Bcc, а `-c` - Сс

Поэтому, соответственно, добавьте флаг `-b` или `-c` перед адресами:

---

```
echo "This is message body" | mail -s "This is Subject" -b someone1@example.com,someone2@example.com
```

---

```
echo "This is message body" | mail -s "This is Subject" -c someone1@example.com,someone2@example.com
```

---

*В связи с комментарием мистера **@de_frag**, данный ответ является **useless**. По этой причине, в дальнейшем я найду рабочий (корректный) вариант, и отредактирую ответ.*

Comment: Первый вариант нерабочий. Нельзя отправить письмо только с получателями `blind copy`. будет ошибка: `Send options without primary recipient specified.`. Письму необходим еще и основной получатель.

Comment: Щас пофикшу, спасибо!

Comment: Сделайте основным получателем отправителя. Это даже будет полезно для отладки. А procmail всегда можно научить резать такую почту.